# Pull different data strings from JSON via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

My client has a jobs board whose API data I'm pulling via Ajax. I can parse the "jobs" data but cannot seem to pull any thing else. For instance, this works to pull the names of job listings to a select box:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'https://api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/roivantsciences/jobs/',
    type:'GET',
    data: 'q=' + "",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( json ) {
        $.each(json.jobs, function(i, value) {
            $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value.title).attr('value', value.title));
        });
    }
});
```

But when I change "json.jobs" to anything else like "json.offices" or "json.locations" nothing is pulled. How do I go about accurately targeting these data strings to cull together for a complete careers page? Appreciate any guidance whatsoever thanks.

This is the JSON if you need to take a look:

```
https://api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/roivantsciences/jobs/
```

Comment: I dont see `offices` or `locations` object in given json

Comment: Sorry meant "location".

Comment: try `$.each(json.jobs, function(i, value) {
            $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value.location).attr('value', value.location));
        });`

Comment: Thanks. It's still pulling the job names not the locations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try pull location.name for all jobs `$.each(json.jobs, function(i, value) { $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value.location.name).att‌​r('value', value.location.name)); })`;

Comment: Thats great. It works but now its pulling every instance of each location, e.g.: it's pulling New York as an `<option>` multiple times. How would I go about consolidating them into groups, perhaps with an integer indicating the number of jobs in each (e.g: "New York (6 jobs)") . Thanks again, clearly I'm extremely new to this...

Answer (score 0):

Ive done a small test:

```
$.ajax({
url:'https://api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/roivantsciences/jobs/',
type:'GET',
data: 'q=' + "",
dataType: 'json',
success: function( json ) {
   console.log(json)
}
```

});

What I got back from console is that your json object only has 'jobs' as the top attribute in it.

You have to go through it like this to get locations:

```
 $.each(json.jobs, function(i, value) {
        console.log(value.location);
    });
```

then you have the location object inside this you got the attribute 'name'

so u can get the names with value.location.name